# How to make scrolling through images as fast as Apple's Photos app

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, performance, three20, image-loading

*The Goal* — On an iPhone, to browse through several hundred locally-stored jpgs using a UIScrollView.

*The Problem* — Like many others before me, I've tried implementing a scroll view based on Apple's [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code and found it lacking. The biggest issue I'm currently up against is that the sample code's architecture doesn't seem to scale. With just a few images loaded from disk, everything's fine. Once the number of images gets into the dozens, though, scrolling suffers terribly: the scrollview stutters mid-scroll with each new swipe.

The only code I've toyed with that comes even close to being reasonably responsive is [Three20](http://three20.info/), but even there the performance doesn't hold a candle to *Photos*.

For now, I'm just using Three20, but a faster, custom solution would definitely be preferable.

Comment: In the end, I went with three20, though I ended up having to tweak the framework to work properly. (I think they've incorporated my bug fix by now, but not sure.) The solution ended up being two-stage loading: first load a tiny thumbnail image so that the user can continue scrolling if they choose, then update that image with a full-resolution copy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [cover flow example,](http://www.e-string.com/content/simple-example-afopenflow-open-source-cover-flow-alternative) it is pretty easy to use and seems to have good performance. I haven't tried it for 100's of images but it could be worth a shot or at least give some ideas.

Comment: Looks like a worthy alternative to propose to my client. That said, it doesn't answer the question, which is specifically about paged scrolling a la _Photos_.